# Displaying Files Name and Link to download in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have files saved in a Project Folder

```
D:\Maarjaa\Marjaa\Content\Uploads
```

Now I want to Display name of these files( not the full URL)

as

```
lakes of kaghan.jpg
lakes of gilgit.jpg
```

not as

```
D:\Maarjaa\Marjaa\Content\Uploads\lakes of kaghan.jpg
```

Additionally I want to give download links to thes files, so that a user can download these files

Comment: This question will not be easily answered in my opinion.  There are different strategies for doing this, but it has little to do with MVC.  Consider starting with creating a custom ViewModel (VM) that loops over the files of the directory, extracting just the file names, and linking to a custom MVC action that will take the given file name and stream it as a download.  Refine your question to be more precise about a problem and I'm sure you'll get help.  But you need to get started by yourself first, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it, In my View

```
 <ul>
            @foreach(var Item in(IEnumerable<Marjaa.Data.MultimediaFile>) ViewData["Files"]) 
            {

               <li><a href=" @Url.Content("~/Content/Uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Item.MultimediaFileUrl))">@System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Item.MultimediaFileUrl)</a> </li>
             }                
            </ul>
```

From my Controller Just Sent a list to View

```
IList<MultimediaFile> list = d.MultimediaFiles.Where(l => l.MultmediaId == id).ToList();
        ViewData["Files"] = list;
```

Answer (score 4):

Many different ways to do this.  Here's one:

Create a class for your files

```
public class Image
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
        }
```

and a view model class

```
public class ViewModel
        {
            public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
        }
```

Then in your controller, populate the view model and the name and path properties for each Image object in the list.  You'll need to import the System.IO namespace.

```
public ActionResult DisplayFilesForDownload( )
        {
            var viewModel = new ViewModel
            {
                Path = @"D:\Maarjaa\Marjaa\Content\Uploads", 
                Images = new List<Image>()
            };
            var paths = Directory.GetFiles(viewModel.Path).ToList();
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo( path );
                var image = new Image
                {
                    Path = path, Name = fileInfo.Name
                };
                viewModel.Images.Add(image);
            }
            return View( viewModel);
        }
```

And the method to allow downloads.  I am assuming all your files are images.  If not, just adjust the MediaTypeName as needed.

```
public FileResult Download(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            var file = File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg, fileName);
            return file;
        }
```

and finally the view.  Image.Name is used to display the shortened file name and Image.Path is used to tell the download method where to fetch the file from.

```
@model FullyQualified.Path.ToYour.ViewModel

@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
    <p>@Html.ActionLink(image.Name, "Download", "ControllerName", new{filePath = image.Path, fileName = image.Name}, null)</p>
}
```

Hope this helps get you on your way.